# How can I use IntelliTrace in WP8 apps?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, intellitrace

I'm using VS0212 Ultimate SP4 and I can't get intellitrace to work in my WP8 project.  Any idea if Windows Phone 8 is supported?

Comment: Yes, windows phone 8 is supported, though I admit I've had a bug or two using it. You have to use catch clauses or it goes to the unhandled exception handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliTrace does not support debugging of Silverlight, Xbox, or Windows Mobile applications.

Please check this link for the better refernce [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Appropriate link for the version of Visual Studio Freeon is using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915(v=vs.110).aspx#IntelliTraceSupport